# await Promises.all SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, async-await

According to this article: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

It seems like it could be possible to use below syntax:

```
let [foo, bar] = await Promise.all([getFoo(), getBar()]);
```

for multiple promises execution. However while using it I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

How can i use `async/await` and `promise.all` to achieve multiple simultaneous operations executed and one resolve with a response.

-----EDITED

the function i am using inside `promise.all` is this one:

```
async function getJson(callback) {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('URL_LINK_HERE');
        let json = await response.json();
        return json;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error!', e);
    }
}
```

as a test field i am using google chrome Version `60.0.3112.113`

Comment: What JS engine are you using? Is it one that supports `await`?

Comment: Try storing what gets returned by the call to `Promise.all(...)` and then `await`ing on what is returned rather than condensing it into a single line.  I had strange results about having complicated instructions.  It was like the compiler wouldn't understand what I actually wanted to wait on sometimes.  I'll see if I can find a concrete example.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome Canary v63

Comment: Is the `await` within an `async` function?

Comment: i am not interested in using this code inside node.js application, so please don't refer to it. its worth adding that function `getJSON` itself is working alright, the problem is when `Promise.all` is used

Comment: Could you post the code that utilizes `Promise.all` itself? If `getJson` is working well, it's most likely something with how you're calling `Promise.all` or the context you're calling it from.

Comment: You need to return `response` from `getJson`, right? Although I don't see how that would cause the syntax error your report. By the way, you might want to think twice about the `catch` in `getJson`, it will prevent the promise rejection from falling through.

Comment: can you propose altered code that doest return error ?

Comment: Personally, I'd let the error in `getJson` fall through, and catch and report it where it is being called from. Anyway, there is about a 99% chance that as @StevenGoodman suggests the problem is that you are using `await` outside an `async` function. Please show us the enclosing function. Note that due a recent change in Chrome, `await` **will** be handled properly at the top level in the console, ie even if not in an async function.

Comment: Please show us the function where you *call* the `getJson` with `Promise.all`, the function where you get the SyntaxErrors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely your code looks something like this:

```js
var thingsDone = await Promise.all([
  Promise.resolve("eat"),
  Promise.resolve("sleep")
]);
console.log(thingsDone);
```

This will not work because the `await` keyword is only valid within an `async` function (which the global context is not). It will simply cause a syntax error.

One way to handle this is to use it like a regular old promise and not using the `await` keyword:

```js
Promise.all([
  Promise.resolve("eat"),
  Promise.resolve("sleep")
]).then((thingsDone) => console.log(thingsDone));
```

Or if you want to get fancy (or need more room to write an expressive function), wrap your logic in an `async` function and then handle it like a promise:

```js
async function doThings() {
  var eat = await Promise.resolve("eat");
  var sleep = await Promise.resolve("sleep");
  return Promise.all([Promise.resolve(eat), Promise.resolve(sleep)]);
}

doThings().then((thingsDone) => console.log(thingsDone));
```

This would allow you to use `await` as needed and is much more helpful in a more complicated function.

Or even more succinctly using an immediately-executing `async` function:

```js
(async() => {
  var eat = await Promise.resolve("eat");
  var sleep = await Promise.resolve("sleep");
  return Promise.all([Promise.resolve(eat), Promise.resolve(sleep)]);
})().then((thingsDone) => console.log(thingsDone));
```

Comment: Posting this answer as a way of better illustrating what's been discussed on the OP's comment chain. May not actually be the answer until OP gives more details on the context in which Promise.all is used

Comment: You say "proper way", but an immediately-executing async function is just as "proper" (if in fact that is the OP's problem).

Comment: What do you mean by an "immediately-executing async function"?

Comment: I mean `(async () => { return await promise; })()`.

Comment: Doesn't that still return a promise which would need to be handled appropriately with `then`/`catch`?

Comment: Yes, but there are cases where this is useful when the insides are more complicated and involve more awaits.

Comment: Updated my answer with some alternative syntax to handle this. Hopefully this helps OP.

Answer (score -1):

torazaburo pointed me to right direction in his comments and i figured it out, this is the final code that is working:

```
var getJson = async function() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json');
        let json = await response.json();
        return json;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error!', e);
    }
}

var check_all = async function(callback) {
    callback( [foo, bar] = await Promise.all([getJson(), getJson()]) );
};

check_all(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This works, example here: https://jsfiddle.net/01z0kdae/1/